# Looking for a hyphen in the first name only

Tags: sas

If I have a dataset containing bunch of names, such as "Steve Jobs", how can I look for names that have a hyphen in the first name only using the proc print command?

Ex:
Dataset ex1 contains

```
name
 --------
Steve Jobs
Steve Job-s <- I do not want this
Ste-ve Jobs <- I want this
```

The code I wrote is the following

```
proc print data=ex1 noobs split=' ';    
    where name like '%-%';
run;
```

My code will print "Steve Job-s" and "Ste-ve Jobs". What can I do to stop "Ste-ve Jobs"?

Comment: Why would you you use proc print for this? Your question is inconsistent in terms of your desired output, please clarify.

Comment: from what I could understand from the OP, he does not want the name ' Steve Jobs' either. And is there any particular reason you disagree with the use of proc print in this case?

Comment: I guess we understand the question differently. IMO Proc Print is for displaying data only. This would appear to be a data cleaning task, so not a filter and if it is data cleaning most likely would need a data set at some point.  Just my experience/opinion, which is why I asked why s/he would use it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `scan()` function to check only the first word for your condition. The third argument specifies a blank as the delimiter; this is necessary because otherwise `-` is included in the default delimiters:

```
where scan(name,1,' ') like '%-%';
```

Comment: index(scan(name,1,' '), '-') > 0;  alternatively

Comment: @vasja This is not equivalent to `%-%`. Something like `Steve- Jobs` will not be filtered.

Comment: @W_ee I'm pretty sure it is equivalent in this case. The `%` wildcard matches a string of zero or more characters.